# How to render word .doc in browse - ASPOSE

Tags: java, html, render, doc, aspose

I'm trying to render a doc in browse, I used aspose.words to a ByteArrayInputStream and saved it as HTML_FIXED.
But I get html instead of an MS WORD layout

**1) JAVA CONTROLLER**

```
public static final String EXAMPLE_HTML = "exHtmlFile";
...
@GetMapping(value = "/example/{code}/{version}")
 public String example(@PathVariable("code") final Long code, @PathVariable("version") final Long version, final Model model) {
      String viewExampleHtml = exampleService.viewExample(code, version);
      model.addAttribute(ModelAttributes.EXAMPLE_HTML, viewExampleHtml );
      model.addAttribute(ModelAttributes.URL_RAIZ, url_raiz);

      return Views.VIEW_EXAMPLE;
    }
```

**2) JAVA SERVICE**

```
public String viewExample(Long code, Long version)
 {
  DownloadResponse response = getResponseExample(code, version);
  //response.getContent() type is ByteArrayInputStream

  com.aspose.words.Document document = new com.aspose.words.Document(response.getContent());
  String filePath = fileServerPath + SEPARATOR + response.getFileName() + ".html";
  //this filePath is correct
  document.save(filePath, SaveFormat.HTML_FIXED);

   FileInputStream entrada = new FileInputStream(filePath);
   InputStreamReader entradaFormatada = new InputStreamReader(entrada);
   BufferedReader entradaString = new BufferedReader(entradaFormatada);

  String linha = entradaString.readLine();
  String html = new String("");
  while (linha != null) {
    html += linha;
    linha = entradaString.readLine();
  }
  entradaString.close();
            
  new File(filePath).delete();
            
  html = removeBackgroungImageFromHtml(html);
            
            
  return html;
}
```

**3)HTML**

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col mb-2">
   <textarea name="exHtml" id="exHtml" rows="10" cols="80" th:text="${exHtmlFile}"></textarea>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you returning the html in a textarea?  They don't render the html.

Comment: The question is not actually related to Aspose.Words. You put HTML into `<textarea>` control, which do not actually render HTML, but is multiline text input control:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp Try using `<embed>` or `<iframe>` controls.